# A function to return 3 random profiles from JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I would like to create a web app that returns 3 random profiles of student that are randomly assigned to you once you click a button. 
I am looking for un function that does that but I can't find anything. Do you have anything that does the job?

[Here](https://github.com/amokranetam/learningweb.git) is the Github repository if you need it.

All I've tried `function(randomusers)` but I failed

```
$.getJSON("https://randomuser.me/api/", function (randomusers) {
    var user = randomusers.results[0];
    document.getElementById("prenom").textContent = (user.name.first); //prénom
    document.getElementById("adresse").textContent = (user.location.street + " " + user.location.city + " " + user.location.state); // adresse
    document.getElementById("email").textContent = (user.email); //email
    var img = document.createElement('IMG'); //profile picture
    img.setAttribute('src', user.picture.large);
    document.getElementById("photo").appendChild(img);
}
```

I want 3 random user profiles to appear when I click the "find my partners" button. Unfortunately, I am not able to display these 3 profiles and anything for the record. Is it that I didn't link the button to the JS function or that the function is wrong?

I am new to coding and I was a bit too ambitious so I have no clue how to do it now.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: SO where is the code that binds the click and calls this code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At the level that I am at right now, the only thing that I can think of is <button onclick="randomuser()">Find my partners</button>. Am I wrong?

Comment: And do you have a function `randomuser`?

Comment: I think I do  $.getJSON( "https://randomuser.me/api/", function( randomusers ) {
var user = randomusers.results[ 0 ];

Comment: Hi @AmokraneT you can use a recursive function to perform asychronous requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to display this in both JavaScript and in JQuery.

You can find the working code sample in this git repository
https://github.com/helloritesh000/DisplayRandom3Profile

Call function *GetRandomProfiles()* on click on button ***Find My Partners***. This will load 1 profile at a time keep clicking the button it will load the another profile.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetRandomProfiles()
    {
        $.getJSON( "https://randomuser.me/api/", function( randomusers ) {
            var user = randomusers.results[0];
            // document.getElementById("picturegenerator").innerHTML = "";

            var img = document.createElement('IMG');
            img.setAttribute('src', user.picture.large);
            document.getElementById("picturegenerator").appendChild(img);

            var detail = document.createElement('div');
            detail.innerHTML = "";

            var prenom = document.createElement('div');
            prenom.setAttribute('id', 'prenom');
            prenom.innerHTML = user.name.first;
            detail.innerHTML += prenom.outerHTML;

            var adresse = document.createElement('div');
            adresse.setAttribute('id', 'adresse');
            adresse.innerHTML = user.location.street +" "+ user.location.city + " " + user.location.state;
            detail.innerHTML += adresse.outerHTML;

            var email = document.createElement('div');
            email.setAttribute('id', 'email');
            email.innerHTML = user.email;
            detail.innerHTML += email.outerHTML;

            document.getElementById("picturegenerator").appendChild(detail);
            } ); 
    }
</script>
```

Another way to achieve is just add the server call in a for loop which runs 3 times. It will pull 3 profiles in single button click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetRandomProfiles()
    {
        for(i=0; i<3;i++)
        {
            $.getJSON( "https://randomuser.me/api/", function( randomusers ) {
            var user = randomusers.results[0];
            // document.getElementById("picturegenerator").innerHTML = "";

            var img = document.createElement('IMG');
            img.setAttribute('src', user.picture.large);
            document.getElementById("picturegenerator").appendChild(img);

            var detail = document.createElement('div');
            detail.innerHTML = "";

            var prenom = document.createElement('div');
            prenom.setAttribute('id', 'prenom');
            prenom.innerHTML = user.name.first;
            detail.innerHTML += prenom.outerHTML;

            var adresse = document.createElement('div');
            adresse.setAttribute('id', 'adresse');
            adresse.innerHTML = user.location.street +" "+ user.location.city + " " + user.location.state;
            detail.innerHTML += adresse.outerHTML;

            var email = document.createElement('div');
            email.setAttribute('id', 'email');
            email.innerHTML = user.email;
            detail.innerHTML += email.outerHTML;

            document.getElementById("picturegenerator").appendChild(detail);
            } );
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ritesh,  I tried your snippet and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help. I am currently trying to get a deeper understanding of your solutions to learn.

Comment: I am glad that it worked, can you please marked it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to do three tasks, and you can do it by using pure JavaScript.

1. Get 3 random users from the API URL (https://randomuser.me/api/) through HTTP request.
2. Collect the random user data in an array.
3. Print the HTML with the proper contents from the array that you have.

With pure JavaScript:

You need to create a helper function to do asynchronous HTTP requests (AJAX). This is a very basic structure for any web project with JavaScript to do asynchronous HTTP requests without any third party library like jQuery. This helper function is kinda similar to `$.get()`, `$.getJSON()`, `$.ajax()` functions in jQuery.

```
var newXHR = null;
function sendXHR(type, responseType, url, data, callback) {
  newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  newXHR.responseType = responseType;
  newXHR.open(type, url, true);
  newXHR.send(data);
  newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
      callback(this.response); // Anonymous function is required at this point: function(argument) { ... }.
    }
  };
}
```

> **Note:**
>
> You can not use a for loop statement with **`asynchronous`** requests
>   because the results can be obtained at an undetermined time, while the
>   execution of a for loop is **`synchronous`**. In that sense, it is
>   quite useful to use a ***callback function*** that allows the
>   continuation of the execution of your code when the previous execution
>   ends in a recursive function with **`asynchronous`** requests.

Then:

1. You may create a recursive function with three parameters: `url`, `times`, `callback`. Where:

   - `url`. It's a string that is the **API URL**: https://randomuser.me/api/.
   - `times`. It's a number. In this case is 3, because you need to do 3 HTTP requests to the **API URL**.
   - `callback`. It's a function reference to execute passed as parameter. *Its value must be a function.* This function reference can receive a value as parameter.

The `count` and `arrayOfUsers` variables must be defined in the global scope.

```
function getUsers(url, times, callback) {
  if (count < times) { // Check the limit in the recursive process. You need to execute this function only 3 times to get 3 random users from the API URL.
    sendXHR("GET", "json", url, null, function(response) { // The response parameter contains the data from the API URL, so you can store this value in an array for every request.
      arrayOfUsers.push(response); // Save the random user data from the API in the array.
      count++; // Increment the counter.
      getUsers(url, times, callback); // Keep executing the function to get more random user data.
    });
  } else {
    callback(arrayOfUsers); // Once reaching the limit return the result of arrayOfUsers through the callback function.
  }
}
```

2. To store random user data obtained from the HTTP request, you can use [Array#push](http://Array.prototype.push()): In this case: `arrayOfUsers.push(response);`.
3. A more practical way to build an HTML markup with data is by concatenating strings.

In this case, I have this function:

```
function renderUsers(data) {
  var html = "", len = data.length, user;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    user = data[i];
    html += "<div class=\"user\"><div><label>Name: </label><span title=\"";
    html += "LastName: ";
    html += user.results[0].name.last;
    html += "\">";
    html += user.results[0].name.first;
    html += "</span></div><div><label>Address: </label><span>";
    html += user.results[0].location.street;
    html += " ";
    html += user.results[0].location.city;
    html += " ";
    html += user.results[0].location.state;
    html += "</span></div><div><label>Email: </label><span>";
    html += user.results[0].email;
    html += "</span></div><div><label>Image: </label><span>";
    html += "<img alt=\"";
    html += user.results[0].picture.large;
    html += "\" src=\"";
    html += user.results[0].picture.large;
    html += "\" /></div></div>";
  }
  return html; // Return the built html.
}
```

You would have something like this:

```js
(function() {
  // Declaring global variables.
  var newXHR = null, arrayOfUsers = [], count = 0;

  // Helper function to make HTTP requests (AJAX) with JavaScript.
  function sendXHR(type, responseType, url, data, callback) {
    newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    newXHR.responseType = responseType;
    newXHR.open(type, url, true);
    newXHR.send(data);
    newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
        callback(this.response);
      }
    };
  }
  // Recursive function to get random users.
  function getUsers(url, times, callback) {
    if (count < times) { // Check the limit in the recursive process. You need to execute this function only 3 times to get 3 random users from the API URL.
      sendXHR("GET", "json", url, null, function(response) { // The response parameter contains the data from the API URL, so you can store this value in an array for every request.
        arrayOfUsers.push(response); // Save the random user data from the API in the array.
        count++; // Increment the counter.
        getUsers(url, times, callback); // Keep executing the function to get more random user data.
      });
    } else {
      callback(arrayOfUsers); // Once reaching the limit return the result of arrayOfUsers through the callback function.
    }
  }
  // Function to render in the page with the random users.
  function renderUsers(data) {
    var html = "", len = data.length, user;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      user = data[i];
      html += "<div class=\"user\"><div><label>Name: </label><span title=\"";
      html += "LastName: ";
      html += user.results[0].name.last;
      html += "\">";
      html += user.results[0].name.first;
      html += "</span></div><div><label>Address: </label><span>";
      html += user.results[0].location.street;
      html += " ";
      html += user.results[0].location.city;
      html += " ";
      html += user.results[0].location.state;
      html += "</span></div><div><label>Email: </label><span>";
      html += user.results[0].email;
      html += "</span></div><div><label>Image: </label><span>";
      html += "<img alt=\"";
      html += user.results[0].picture.large;
      html += "\" src=\"";
      html += user.results[0].picture.large;
      html += "\" /></div></div>";
    }
    return html; // Return the built html.
  }

  var btnFindMyPartners = document.getElementById("btnFindMyPartners");
  btnFindMyPartners.onclick = function() {
    var users = document.getElementById("users");
    users.removeAttribute("hidden");
    users.textContent = "Loading...";
    arrayOfUsers = []; // Reset array of users.
    count = 0;
    getUsers("https://randomuser.me/api/", 3, function(data) {
      document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = renderUsers(data);
    });
  };
}());
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

button {
  border: #819bc2 solid 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#users,
#users .user,
#users .user div,
button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#users {
  border: #819bc2 solid 1px;
}

#users .user {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cfcee6, #fff);
  border: #46628c solid 1px;
  box-shadow: inset #92979c 0 0px 20px 0px;
}

#users .user div {
  border: #d4dbe7 solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnFindMyPartners">Find my partners</button>
<div id="users" hidden>
</div>
```

I would like to remind you of the following when you build HTML markup dynamically.

[**HTML5 - The id attribute**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> The `id` attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

Hope this helps a little bit more.